# SQL Select - Fetching two different values from another table based on two different IDs

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables

Table 1 has five columns

```
EmployeeID,
EmployeeCarModelID,
EmployeeCarModelName,
SpouseCarModelID,
SpouseCarModelName
```

Table 2 has two columns

```
CarModelID, 
CarModelName
```

How would I construct a select statement which will pull through the `CarModelName` to both the `EmployeeCarModelName` and the `SpouseCarModelName` based on their respective IDs? I'm not sure I can use a JOIN statement to do this as we are looking at two different id columns within the same table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two joins to do this. I think you want:

```
select t1.EmployeeId, t1.EmployeeCarModelID, t2emp.CarModelName as EmployeeCarModelName,
       t1.SpouseCarModelID, t2sp.CarModelName as SpouseCarModelName
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2emp
     on t1.EmployeeCarModelID = t2emp.CarModelId left join
     table2 t2sp
     on t1.SpouseCarModelId = t2sp.CarModelId;
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much Gordon. That's exactly what I needed!